# Heroku | Need help get java servlet running as home page

Tags: java, servlets, heroku, web, heroku-postgres

I got this App running locally and on Heroku.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

It simple displays a html file with hello world. I want to modify it or find a new template that initially runs a servlet(that I create). It generates my home page which pulls data from PostgreSQL. I have been at this 30 hours with no luck. I have before built a java web application locally using local SQL and NetBeans. 
I have went through most heroku tutorials on java web apps. There very limited

I would give my left nut to get up and running. I just cant find any help to start it going, start the ball rolling. It's so depressing. I just can't connect to dots together to get going

Any help would be so so so well received

Thanks guys

Comment: I dunno man, nothing working for me at all. im trying to get this modified for servelts 
https://github.com/rajdeepd/heroku-spring-boot-jdbc-psql

Answer (score -1):

You should read Heroku's [Getting Started with Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction) guide.

Comment: Yep. Read them all, tried like 20 different clones, have them all working locally and on heroku. I still cant get running, with my skill level. I have made App before locally, good ones with loads of servelts and pages pulling data from local sql. 
As of now after 50+ hours, i still cant get my app with a home page with a few bits from a database with heroku
I have a new app template im trying out
[link]https://github.com/rajdeepd/heroku-spring-boot-jdbc-psql

Not having much luck, 
Im trying to make servelt pages the ways im used to, tough, using spring boot now, new for me